# Index of figures producing incorrect output?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have created an automatic index of figures in MS word. It was working just fine and everything was displayed correctly. Recently, I added two more figures in the middle of the document. Now the index of figures does not display the index of second figure/

Comment: You have selected the table of figures and updated it? (F9 on Windows Word, either F9 or fnF9 on Mac Word depending on your keyboard). Most fields are at best semi-automatic - you have to update them to see the result of changes you have made elsewhere in the document.

Comment: Yes I updated the index of figures but nothing happened.

Comment: A number of things could be wrong, but I doubt I can enumerate them all. Having change tracking switched on can cause problems with cross-referencing. Having captions inside "graphics layer" objects such as text boxes will probably cause problems. I would verify that all the captions use the same sequence name (the one inside the SEQ field). Beyond that, best to post a copy of your document somewhere accessible so people can take a look.